# Filter Graph API Azure AD Inactive Users

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to filter users who have not logged in for the last 30 days (both interactive and non-interactive) and whose assigned license is Microsoft 365 E5. I am attempting the below query, but it doesn't seem to be working.

(line breaks better for readability)

```http
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users
?filter=signInActivity/lastSignInDateTime le @{addDays(utcNow(), -30)}
&signInActivity/lastNonInteractiveSignInDateTime le @{addDays(utcNow(), -30)}
&assignedLicenses/any(s:s/skuId eq 184efa21-98c3-4e5d-95ab-d07053a96e67)
&$select=displayName,userPrincipalName,signInActivity
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-beta) on `signInActivity`:

> Get the last signed-in date and request ID of the sign-in for a given user. Read-only.
>
> Returned only on $select. Supports $filter (eq, ne, not, ge, le) **but not with any other filterable properties.**

This implies the issue is your filter is on both `signInActivity` and `assignedLicenses` properties. For your purposes, I'd suggest adding `assignedLicenses` to your `$select` and then do the `skuId` filtering client-side.

It isn't entirely clear from you query how the output of `addDays(utcNow(), -30)` is formatted, but it could be a potential source of issues as well. Since `lastSignInDateTime` is a `dateTimeOffset` type, the date must be formatted as ISO 8601 and include the time zone offset (`2023-03-19T00:00:00Z`).